# Discord.js v13 setTimeout() working differently than expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I have this command which is supposed to ping a user 10 times, because of discord limitations it sends 5 pings and then has to wait a sec to send the next 5. I tried to make it send pings every 3 seconds to prevent that from happening but all it does is it waits 3 seconds before sending the first mention and that's it, the rest are send without any down time (except for discord limitations ofc). Anyone got a solution?
Here's my code:

```js
const { Permissions } = require('discord.js')

module.exports = {
    name: 'pings',
    description: "pings someone",
    execute(message, args)
    {
        const target = message.mentions.members.first()
        if (message.member.user.id === 'my discord id' || message.member.permissions.has(Permissions.FLAGS.ADMINISTRATOR))
        {
            if(target)
            {
                for(let i = 10; i > 0; i--)
                {
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        message.channel.send(`<@${target.id}>`)
                    }, 3000);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                message.reply('You have to mention someone in this server')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's just how you wrote it to work. You have a loop that says "Run this code 10 times". that code, which runs 10 times, one after the other, *with no delay*, says "In 3 seconds, do this". So after 3 seconds, all 10 occur.

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the loop to do this. Currently this is what you have:

```
      for(let i = 10; i > 0; i--)
        {
            setTimeout(function(){
                message.channel.send(`<@${target.id}>`)
            }, 3000);
        }
```

But this just sends 10 messages with a 3 second delay (each message is sent after 3 seconds). Instead, do:

```
            for(let i = 10; i > 0; i--)
            {
                setTimeout(function(){
                    message.channel.send(`<@${target.id}>`)
                }, i*3000);                                   // Adding i*3000
            }
```

Now this will send 10 messages, one at 3, 6, 9... and 30 seconds.